# "He is me" — is this grammatical?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions

Referring to a picture, the question is "Who is he?" The answer I got back was "he is me". Is that correct? Shouldn't it be "It is me"?

Comment: The bit about "quality standards" is an automated thing.  When a question is very short, for example, it may get that response. See here http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2227/ or here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92074/

Comment: Hi Julie. Welcome to English.SE. As GEdgar says, Quality standards is done by the SE Engine when you post something as "low quality"... Have a look at the [meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92074) if you require the explanation briefly. And, please don't add that as a *complaint* to your question...

Comment: If you want to be technically correct, it should be *"he is I."*

Comment: *I* as the object?

Comment: If you want to sound ridiculous and persist in the belief that English 'rules' stopped evolving (just) before you went to school, use 'He is I.' (_complement_ with a link-verb, not object, Jon)

Comment: I'd use 'whimsy quotes' to show a faintly humorous retort: " 'He' is me!" The usual answer would be "it's me" or "That's me!"

Comment: @EdwinAshworth You are correct. I confused myself because when I expanded the statements to provide an answer I changed the case. František is correct in *I* being used in this case, and you are in *me* also being used in this case, and becoming more common.

Comment: It is I, Leclerc!

Comment: They have different rules in wartime France. They mongle their grimmer.

Comment: @Jon Hanna: Becoming more common? At http://www.universityofcalifornia.edu/news/article/4225 : Myth: Expressions like "It was me" and "She was taller than him" are incorrect; the correct forms are "It was I" and "She was taller than he." 

Pullum responds: The forms with nominative pronouns sound ridiculously stuffy today. In present-day English, the copular verb takes accusative pronoun complements and so does "than." My advice would be this: If someone knocks at your door, and you say "Who's there?" and what you hear in response is "It is I," don't let them in. It's no one you want to know.

Answer (score 3):

There seem to me to be two reasonable and idiomatic native-speaker answers to the question "Who is he?"

> "**He**" is me. [This, of course, is written English, and the bold font and quotation marks indicate that when spoken, the word *he* should be emphasized.  It's almost the same as responding to *Who's that guy in the white jacket?* with "**That guy's**" me.]
>
> That's me. [A native speaker probably wouldn't say "It is me" or even "It's me" but "That's me".]

Answer (score 2):

"It [the subject of the portrait] is me" and "He [the person who is the subject of the portrait] is me" are both correct.

Some people may favour the latter, because it's already established that the portrait is of a person (and perhaps, that it is of a male person).

Some may favour the former because in most contexts "he" and "me" would be mutually exclusive, which makes it sound a bit strange.

Sounding strange doesn't make something wrong. It's strange to be talking of the same person with the third and first person in the same clause, because contexts in which that makes sense are very rare, and in most exceptions the neuter third person ("it") are more appropriate for some other reason. This is though a case where it would make sense.

Comment: The _it_ used in response to  "Who is he?" would have to be the delexical one (unless the picture showed a very blurred dog, say). Certainly, in "It's me," _it_ is the delexical variant: French _ce_, not French _il_, as in _c'est moi_ not _il est moi_. Compare "It's us" and contrast "We [the subject of the portrait] ...

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes, that just occurred to me, and it would cover a lot of other "it is me" and "it is I" cases.

Comment: +1 for being technically and popularly correct at once.

Answer (score 2):

It's fine, just an attempt at a tiny bit of humor.  In a similar vein you may have run across statements such as "... the cavalry is us" (Mystery Men), "We have met the enemy and he is us" (Pogo), etc.  It's a wry comment on the irony of the unexpected.

Comment: The Pogo quote is an allusion to Admiral O. H. Perry's victorious battle report during the War of 1812: _We have met the enemy and they are ours_

Answer (score 1):

"I am he" is *also* grammatically correct, although its emphasis is slightly different.

> "I am looking for Andrew Lazarus." 
>   "I am he."